# Difference between GET and HEAD in the default implementation of yii\rest\ActiveController

Tags: rest, yii2

I have [created a blank *Yii 2 Advanced Project Template*](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#installing-using-composer) and added [default REST *UserController*](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#creating-controller):

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

When my test client (Insomia) is sending GET and HEAD requests to the above controller:

```
GET http://localhost/yii-advanced/api/web/users
GET http://localhost/yii-advanced/api/web/user/2
```

vs.:

```
HEAD http://localhost/yii-advanced/api/web/users
HEAD http://localhost/yii-advanced/api/web/user/2
```

(I use [my own configuration](https://onezeronull.com/2021/06/03/pluralized-and-non-pluralized-rules-for-the-same-rest-controller/) thus I have both [pluralized](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$pluralize-detail) and non-pluralized routes)

The only differences that I see are:

- HEAD doesn't return any body (and thus)
- GET has additional entry among headers: "Content-Length"

Is this correct or am I missing something obvious?

If this is correct and expected behavior then why would I need / like to use HEAD verb call, if it brings me no additional information than GET call does?

Comment: By the spec HEAD should also return content-length but we might have it done to get this value only when generating the response body, I'll check.

Comment: Hmm, nope, it looks that Yii is not adding/removing this header in the usual case (the exception is the file to be downloaded) so it must depend on your server and thus, since Yii is not returning any content for the response in case of HEAD method your server will not include the length header.

Comment: @Bizley What you wrote in your comment (thanks!) seems to be self-explanatory. Meaning: no content = no length in header). But the question remains: What is the difference and why should bother / care / use about HEAD. The only reasoning that comes to my mind is: with HEAD you are getting the same as with GET _without_ content and that is expected. In my case GET returns a dozen of records, but it could easily return millions of them, making response very heavy. So I use HEAD instead in order to get i.e. links, pagination info etc. But I am not sure if above has any sense?

Comment: As I understand HEAD is made to allow you to test your future GET request and see what headers you will get. It should be useful for example for a large content to prepare for that fetch but in this case, you will not get the info without additional custom preparation of the response object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with HEAD you are getting the same as with GET *without content* and that is expected.

GET can return a dozen of records, but it could easily return millions of them, making response very heavy. So you should use HEAD instead in order to get i.e. links, pagination info etc.